# What type of buildings offer what level of jobs?

Tags: simcity-2013

There are three tiers of workers (as is everything else); tier 1, 2 and 3. What I am having a hard time with is figuring out what I can build to target workers from each of the tiers. I gather what I am sure everyone else has, low tech industrial (regardless of density really) provides mostly tier 1 jobs.

But what are my other building options for tier 1 jobs? If I want to target tier 2 or 3 what types of buildings should I consider?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Commercial buildings  (note - single shift versions exist and have half the jobs).

```
                       Total     §   §§  §§§  Tax@10%
§   LD  (1x2)             14    10    4    0
§§  LD  (2x2)             12     6    4    2
§§§ LD  (2x2)              6     3    2    1
§   MD  (1x4)             76    60   16    0     §110
§§  MD  (4x4)             34    20   10    4
§§§ MD  (4x4)             30    10   12    8
§   HD  (2x4)            710   600  100   10     §260
§§  HD  (4x4)            670   400  200   70
§§§ HD  (4x4)            620   200  300  120
```

Industrial buildings

```
                       Total     §   §§  §§§   Tax@10%
T1 LD  (2x4)              26    20    6    0       §80
T1 MD  (4x4)             172   140   20   12      §320
T1 HD  (8x4)            1620  1400  200   20      §800

T2 LD  (2x4)              24   12    8     4       §90
T2 MD  (4x4)             132   80   40    12      §370
T2 HD  (8x4)            1330  800  400   130      §920

T3 LD  (2x4)              22    4   10     8
T3 MD  (4x4)              92   20   60    12
T3 HD  (8x4)             940  200  600   140
```

Utilities

```
Garbage Dump              26   20    6     0
Large Fire Station       172  140   20    12
Police Precinct           76   60   16     0
Recycling Center         132   80   40    12
Water Pumping Station    132   80   40    12
```

Education

```
Community College         50   40   10     0
University               460  320  100    40
```

Metal Working

```
Smelting Factory        1620  1400  200   20
Trade Depot               26    20    6    0
Trade Port                56    40   12    4
Processor Factory         92    20   60   12
Consumer Electronics    1040   200  600  240
```

Power Plants

```
Coal Power Plant          26    20    6    0
Oil Power Plant           56    40   12    4

Reflecting Pool            7     5    2    0
Amphitheater               7     5    2    0
```

And, because I'm having so much fun bulldozing things... residential building values for workers, shoppers and students:

```
                Workers Shoppers Students  Tax@10%
§   LD  (1x2)         4        2        2
§   MD  (1x4)        40       20       15
§   MD  (2x4)        40       20       15
§   HD  (4x4)       400      200      100     §200

§§  LD  (1x2)         2        1        2
§§  MD  (4x4)        20       10       10
§§  HD  (4x4)       200      100       50     §240

§§§ LD  (4x2)         2        1        1
§§§ MD  (4x4)         7        3        4
§§§ HD  (4x4)        70       33       30     §280
```

Additional information

```
Modules do not have influence.
```

Comment: A T instead of $ may work better.. and do you think turning on/off the buildings would work as well? (I can not test that where I am but I do not relish bulldozing my nuclear plant to figure that one out :))

Comment: @James turning on/off buildings should work fine for counts. I have moved workers from my coal mine to my community college by doing that.

Comment: Now with actual measured numbers.  More as time permits.

Comment: also added some measured numbers for electronics industry