# Where are all the metrics?

Tags: simcity-2013

How do I find all the basic information about buildings, such as, for instance and among other things:

- Workers needed
- Residents housed
- Power/water consumed
- etc.

It's occasionally tricky to make managerial decisions without at least a sense of these things…

*Edit:* While I'm aware of the general overview tools, what I really want is detailed information on a per-building basis, including capacities as well as usage.

Answer (score 3):

To see all kind of information about workers, shoppers, jobs etc but also about your residents, click on the Population count bar (roughly in the middle of the toolbar on the lower edge of the screen, it shows how many residents your town has). There are two tabs, open the second one (forgot the name), there you will find a table of all workers grouped by their wealth class. In the table you will see how many workers there are in each wealth class, how many are commuting from other towns in the region, how many are commuting out into the region and also how many jobs there are for the respective wealth classes.
There more more tables pertaining to commercials and industry.

To see water/power usage, click on the respective tool (as if you wanted to build a power plant or water tower). With the tool selected, on the right-hand side you will see a gauge with red/yellow/green zones. If you hover mouse over this gauge, the tooltip will provide information about production/usage/import/export and excess of the respective resource.
Analogically for sewage, garbage etc..

Answer (score 3):

Here's residential agents housed.

```
  $  Low (1×2)    4w   2sh   2st
  $  Mid (1×4)   40w  20sh  15st
  $  Mid (2×4)   40w  20sh  15st
  $ High (4×4)  400w 200sh 100st

 $$  Low (1×2)   2w   1sh    2st
 $$  Mid (4×4)  20w  10sh   10st
 $$ High (4×4) 200w 100sh   50st

$$$ Low  (4×2)   2w   1sh    1st
$$$ Mid  (4×4)   7w   3sh    4st
$$$ High (4×4)  70w  33sh   30st
```

You can determine the worker, power, and water stats for any building you control by toggling the power and comparing the city overall stats.  Those stats are updated instantly for capacity.  *Pause the game*, turn a building off, write down the city stats for workers (population->details), power (power plant menu) and water (water pump menu), then power the building on and recheck the stats.

There are also worker stats for many of the buildings you don't control at [this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108399/what-type-of-buildings-offer-what-level-of-jobs).

Answer (score -1):

> While I'm aware of the general overview tools, what I really want is detailed information on a per-building basis, including capacities as well as usage.

The problem is that there is no such thing. Just like the sim-poo that flows to your water filtration plants your sim-citizens have no fixed work or home! So it really changes on a per day basis.

The game doesn't have fixed citizens per say: some attributes such as education/money/happiness do persist but name/relations/home/job don't.

- An entity (person) enters into the system and moves to a house and is added into the population of that building.
- The next day the house emit x entities who then determines what the closest jobs/school/etc sink and goes there.

That's why you see extremely weird behaviours in the mid/late game: hordes of pedestrians running around the city getting to their 'sinks' too late, mass traffic jams as sim try and get to some destinations over others. Unlike other games, like Tropico, you can bulldoze that factor and know that Pedro won't run off and join the rebels.

What I ultimately suggest is treating your industrial, etc. as job sinks... if there are too many unfilled jobs bulldoze, if there aren't then build.

> How do I find all the basic information about buildings, such as, for instance and among other things:
>
> - Workers needed
> - Residents housed
> - Power/water consumed

You can refer to the [imgur sim guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn2ED.jpg) that has been passed around. This has a breakdown for all of the relative power/water/sims created/sims req'd/etc for RCI buildings.. however it is still missing all of the specialist building which, quite frankly, you will be using most of the time.

In a nutshell, there are two factors:

- Building density, which is determined by traffic, and
- Wealth/Techonology level

  - Level of education determines level of industry
  - Level of industry determines level of residents
  - Level of residents determines level of commerce

Basically, the higher the density, the higher the level of a building, the higher its  requirements. High level, high density areas can handle hundreds of sims but require the most water and power.

```
Water/Energy requirements in a scale from 0 to 5
RESIDENTIAL AREAS    COMMERCIAL AREAS     INDUSTRIAL AREAS
───────────────────  ───────────────────  ─────────────────
  Low Med Hi Wealth    Low Med Hi Wealth    Low Med Hi Tech
L 0/1 0/1 1/2        L 0/1 0/1 1/2        L 0/1 2/3 3/4
M 0/1 1/2 2/2        M 0/1 1/2 2/2        M 2/2 3/4 4/5
H 1/2 2/2 3/2        H -/- 2/2 2/3        H 3/3 4/4 5/5
Density              Density              Density

Population cap       Total employees      Total employees
RESIDENTIAL AREAS    COMMERCIAL AREAS     INDUSTRIAL AREAS
───────────────────  ───────────────────  ─────────────────
  Low Med Hi Wealth    Low Med Hi Wealth    Low Med Hi Tech
L   6   3   1        L   2   2   3        L   4   4   4 
M  60  30  10        M  20  20  25        M  40  40  40 
H 600 300 100        H   - 200 200        H 400 400 400
Density              Density              Density

Employees in       │   --- Low --- --- Med --- --- Hi  --- Wealth
COMMERCIAL AREAS   │ L   2+  0+  0   1+  1+  0   1+  1+  1
                   │ M   2+ 18+  0  10+ 10+  0   5+ 10+  5
Low+Med+Hi         │ H     N/A     100+100+  0  50+100+ 50
education          │ Density

Employees in       │   --- Low --- --- Med --- --- Hi  --- Tech
INDUSTRIAL AREAS   │ L   4+  0+  0   2+  2+  0   2+  1+  1
                   │ M  35+  5+  0  30+  8+  2  20+ 10+ 10
Low+Med+Hi         │ H 300+ 90+ 10 200+150+ 50 100+200+100
education          │ Density
```

Comment: Not having a fixed work or home doesn't imply that buildings don't have capacities.