# What are the stats for the MegaTower segments?

Tags: simcity-2013

Cities of Tomorrow introduced MegaTowers, which have many different segments which can be built.

So far I know these:

```
LW Residential: 800 workers, 400 shoppers and 200 students.
  800 cost per hour, 1200 rent per hour
T1 Office: 1200 LW, 400 MW and 100 HW workers.
  900 cost per hour, 1900 rent per hour.
  (no pollution, no freight, immune to techpoints)
```

I'm mainly interested in residential agent counts, goods counts, worker counts, cost and max rent per hour, and power consumption (in 10's of power units).  My theory is that these buildings pay less in rent and take more in power than equivalent original RCI would pay in tax.

Comment: In the spirit of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108399/what-type-of-buildings-offer-what-level-of-jobs

Comment: Is this even playable yet?  I thought it isn't released until the 14th.

Comment: I played it last night.

Comment: simcity.com says Cities of Tomorrow is available now. I'm not sure if it is available currently worldwide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Apartment" is the name for Residential MegaTower segments.  It has workers and shoppers of matching wealth type + students.  It accumulates education level as you'd expect.

```
    Workers Shoppers Students Income Expense Power
LW      800     400       200   1200     800 4.8 MW
MW      400     200       100   1800    1320 2.4 MW
HW      200     100        50   3600    3320 1.2 MW
```

"Mall" is the name for Commercial MegaTower segments.  There are no Souvenirs. There are no freight orders.

```
   Goods Jobs Income Expense Power
LW  1500 ~175   1250     730 1.4 MW
MW   750 ~125   1750    1150 2.7 MW
HW   375  ~77   3100    2150 2.7 MW
```

"Office" is the name for Industrial MegaTower segments.  There is no pollution.  There is no freight produced.  They do not consume tech points.

```
    LWJobs MWJobs HWJobs Income Expense Power
T1     600    200     50   2550     950  9.7 MW
T2     400    200    100   3880    1460 10.6 MW
T3     200    200    150   4960    2480  8.4 MW
```

Notes:

- Numbers with "~" were not precisely measured.
- MW and T2 structures are same whether built with MegaTower art or Elite MegaTower art.
- Residential numbers are occupants
- Income, Expense, Power are per hour
- Jobs and Goods are per shift (12 hour cycle).  Double these numbers to get daily totals.

Strategy Notes:

- Residential units pay ~500 simoleans per hour if everything works perfectly.  Not good for making money.
- Billboard crowns add a bonus for Commercial and Industrial units in the tower.  These crowns are very important for money making.  HW C makes 950 net income without crowns and 4050 net income with full crowns.
- Offices pay more based on wealth levels of workers.  More than 50% of the income from T3 Office comes from the 150 HW workers.