# How do I get rid of low wealth demand in jobs?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have been working on a nice balance between demand and jobless citizens.
When I look at my demand, I can see the companies in my city, only want low wealth workers. How do I remove this demand? I tried to destroy industrials which didn't look like high-tech. This seemed to work, but when I want to create new industrial for high-tech industrial, only low tech industrial will pop-up. I also tried the same with commercial and have the same effect (but then instead of tech, the demand of low wealth will increase and so does the demand of high wealth).
I want the following effect: Decrease of low wealth demand. Increase of high wealth demand and little bit mid wealth demand. Can anyone tell me which factors I should look at and how I can make this possible?

This seems to happen:
[image]

Comment: Utopia means "no place".

Answer (score 3):

The vast majority of commercial/industrial buildings want more low-paid grunts than medium-paid staff and high-paid executives. (For example, one building might want 140 low-wealth, 20 mid-wealth, and 12 high-wealth. A list is [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108399/what-type-of-buildings-offer-what-level-of-jobs?rq=1); even the buildings that want more mid-wealth workers have pretty high demand for low-wealth as well.) If you want the demand to go away, you need more low-wealth residential areas.

Comment: But then again, I don't have the space in my city for low-wealth residentials, however I could make use of other cities in the region right? Well, I tried that too. But they rather stay in their hometown/city :c And the city I tried that on also has a lot of homeless somehow. I have no clue on how to get rid of this.

Comment: There has to be a surplus of workers in another city before they start looking in yours for jobs. But hey, at least you're on the right side of the jobs situation - it's better to have too many jobs available than not enough.